# Slow Gnome shell?

Tags: linux, performance, fedora-22

it's been a few days that my Fedora 22 is acting really slow. When I write text, it takes a few ms to appears, the mouse moves by jumps (not smooth).

I have rebooted the computer multiple times, it's not the issue. I have a `AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1055T Processor` with 8Go of Ram, I don't believe it should be that slow.

As a text, I've run `glxgears` and get a

```
302 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.398 FPS
```

Once I start moving the mouse over the gears, I drop to :

```
224 frames in 5.0 seconds = 44.772 FPS
231 frames in 5.0 seconds = 46.076 FPS
```

Here's `top` :

```
top - 12:25:21 up 1 day,  3:34,  3 users,  load average: 0,46, 0,95, 1,04
Tasks: 263 total,   1 running, 262 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7,3 us,  9,8 sy,  0,4 ni, 82,5 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  8156456 total,  2400452 free,  3091628 used,  2664376 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2915324 total,  2915324 free,        0 used.  4714032 avail Mem
```

Do you know what is causing this?

I only have Chrome and rhytmbox running.

**Update**: I switched to Firefox to check that the issue was not Chrome related. This seemed bo have fixed the issue, but just for a few hours. The computer is now back to having lags when I write and move the mouse.

Here's a `free -h` export; The memory doesn't seems to be full.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,8G        2,0G        2,1G        124M        3,7G        5,6G
Swap:          2,8G          0B        2,8G
```

If you need more commands output, please ask :)

Comment: What graphic card do you have? It has more influence on GUIs - at least from my experience. If you have older one, it can be slow for more complex GUIs like Gnome or Unity. Also not so good drivers may cause this (I have opensource drivers for new Nvidia cards and *everything* works really bad on my second laptop). Looking at you card and Linux compatibility might help you.

Comment: I have an `ATI Radeon HD 5500 series`. The drivers are `radeon`

Comment: Those seem to me as opensource drivers, which not always work properly. You can try the proprietary ones if you are not strictly against it (I found [something here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst131ProprietaryLinuxGraphicsDriverReleaseNotes.aspx), but it seems to be older). Just take care and make a backup (I remember reinstalling the whole system because the proprietary Nvidia drivers screwed up everything). Since I have no experience with Radeon cards, this is the best advice I can give you, but graphic cards are pain with Linux :/

Comment: I just tried something : I swictched from Chrome to Fedora, and the slowness has stopped! It seems it's Chrome that is behind this issue!

Comment: You mean switched to Firefox? I'm a bit confused now :D However, I'm glad you solved it!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I switched to Firefox, which seemed to have fixed the issue, but finally no, I still have those lags when I write text, move the mouse, etc. I updated the question with the `free -h` command, which disturbs me because there seems to be no abuse in the memory. :/

Comment: Have you enabled or used Flash or Flash plugin in Firefox (AFAIK it's built-in in Chrome)? For me it sometimes crashed the whole Firefox / Chrome and also Gnome. If your problem is continuing in both browsers and memory seems to be OK, then this may be the cause. However, I am just guessing based on my experience.